# Add transitions to the PowerPoint slides with PptxGenJS

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, pptxgenjs

Recently, I have been playing with the PptxGenJS API to generate some cool PowerPoint slides and I want to add some transitions to the slides.  I don't see any documentation describing the process of adding transitions.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think they currently dont have animation support like the offical powerpoint api from microsoft(office) you can maybe try changing the package. They use  Open Office XML (OOXML)